# How do I write a select statement that show only rows that consist of cars made from pure letters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

For example I had a table named car with two columns named column1 and column2

for now I'm gonna insert some values to these columns like

```
insert into car(column1,column2)
values('BMW XL','XL BMW')

insert into car(column1,column2)
values('3Benz AMG', 'AMG Benz')

insert into car(column1,column2)
values('Ford! XC', 'XC Ford')
```

Now I want to write a select statement by using regexp_like regular expression to return only show cars made by pure letters(which means that only show 'BMW' AND 'XL'), so how do I do that, I'm appreciate for your suggestions.

Comment: `only show 'BMW' AND 'XL'` means record only contain Upper case `A-Z` or may contains `numbers` also

Comment: Not familiar with the `regexp_like` function, but this regex should do the trick, assuming columns are concatenated for the match: `/^([A-z]+)$/`

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper  thanks for ur reply sir and I tried this:                              select column1,column2 from car where regexp_like(column1,'[A-Z]')  however it still return all the things to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider this query. This regular expression will check if any of column values contains at least 1 invalid non-alphabets.

```
select * from car   
where regexp_substr(regexp_replace(column1, '[[:space:]]*',''), '([^[:alpha:]])') is null
        and  regexp_substr(regexp_replace(column2, '[[:space:]]*',''), '([^[:alpha:]])') is null
```

try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=68ae693b64326ea79844c83fe73903bc)

Comment: thanks for ur reply again sir! I tried this but it didn't show anything to me

Comment: @TIGUZI, try again

Comment: same result... nothing return

Comment: @TIGUZI, please check dbfiddle link

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't post my problem correctly, could you please check my post again? I'm so sorry.

Comment: Thanks you sir it's working! I didn't learn regular expression before, that's really hard for me right now, that's suffering and hairs keep falling, anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe, you want:

```
where regexp_like(column1, '^[A-Za-z ]+$') and
      regexp_like(column2, '^[A-Za-z ]+$')
```

Or, you can phrase this as not having any other characters:

```
where not regexp_like(column1, '[^A-Za-z ]') and
      not regexp_like(column2, '[^A-Za-z ]')
```